# C# text file sharing scheme for multiple users

Tags: c#, filestream, file-locking, filelock, multi-user

Instead of me writing from scratch a text file sharing windows form application, I thought I would simply ask if someone has a snippet (C#) or methodology that I could use?

The application merely needs to create a text file and allow multiple users using the same application from different pcs on the network to append comments to the file.  Basically, I am trying to get multiple users to give frequent updates/comments/status changes to a project with this simple app.

I have looked into some filestream locking suggestions, but again, would like to see if anyone would be willing to share a code snippet.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.
Dell

Answer (score 2):

Try using `System.IO.File.AppendText` method this does everything you are looking for file operation

> **Remarks taken from MSDN**
>
> StreamWriter(String, Boolean) constructor overload. If the file
>   specified by path does not exist, it is created. If the file does
>   exist, write operations to the StreamWriter append text to the file.
>   Additional threads are permitted to read the file while it is open.
>
> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path
>   information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to
>   the current working directory. To obtain the current working
>   directory, see GetCurrentDirectory.
>
> The path parameter is not case-sensitive.This method is equivalent to the

Answer (score 0):

Use Client-Server approach, for example make a WCF service with 2 methods AppendText and GetText, and then only WCF service would write to file.

Here is the example of basic WCF client-server

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication